# Perl Regular Expression - Dynamic Matches

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I want to match and capture 5 integers separated by one or more spaces - example input:

> 1111        234            3333          456    7890

I could do this:

```
my $input = '1111        234            3333          456    7890';
if($input =~ /^\s*([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)/)
{
  #$1 = '1111', $2 = '234', $3 = '3333', $4= '456', $5 = '7890'
}
```

But I want to do something like this to keep the regex simpler, rather than repeating each int 5 times explicitly:

```
my $input = '1111        234            3333          456    7890';
if($input =~ /^((\s*[0-9]+){5})/)
{
  #$1 = '1111        234            3333          456    7890';
  #$2 = ' 7890'
  #all other capture variables are undefined
}
```

However, the captures don't seem to work out.

**Is there a way I can I do this and still access my 5 captures?**

Even better would be an unknown number of captures:

```
my $input = '1111        234            3333          456    7890';
if($input =~ /^((\s*[0-9]+)+)/)
{
   #foreach capture 1..N do something...
}
```

Comment: `my @numbers = $input =~ /\d+/g` ?

Comment: Are you are looking for code that would take exactly 5 elements from input? If so, check the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @numbers = $input =~ /\d+/g;
```

The global flag will return all the matches in list context, which will be stored in your array.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote? He explicitly asked to capture integers separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what your delimiter is (in this case, one or more spaces), then you don't need a regex to capture what you want.  You can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = "1111        234            3333          456    7890";
my @ints=split /\s+/,$input;
print "$_\n" foreach(@ints);
```

Which produces the output:

```
1111
234
3333
456
7890
```

Comment: yes that will work thanks - and probably what I will do.  i'd still like to know if this is possible as I am parsing a text file need the regex to know if I'm a match, so it would nice to match and capture in one step rather than 2 steps - match, then split.

Comment: Well, in your file, you can run the lines through the regex `/((?:\d+\s+)+)\d+/` which should match on one or more digits separated by one or more spaces.  Then, if you get a match to that regex, split the match on `/\s+/` and go from there.

Comment: @JackManey I think there's a serial downvoter around.. seen questions where every answer + question is downvoted for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is the pattern of the line always digit groups separated by spaces? If so, rather than the regex, why not split into array based on whitespace

```
@outArray = split (/ +/,$input);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following would capture the first 5 integers and ignore any after that if thats what you're after. I may not be entirely clear.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in = '1111        234            3333          456    7890 12 13';

my @ints = (split ' ', $in)[0 .. 4];

print "@ints\n";
```

Prints:

```
1111 234 3333 456 7890
```

Chris

Comment: I thought there migth be more than 5 by the way he worded his question. I wasn't clear about his intent.

Comment: no I wasn't - I kind of asked both but am happy with either answer.  thanks